# How is orthogonality in $L^1$ space defined?

Tags: functional-analysis

I couldn't find anything about "orthogonality in $L^1$ space", its norm is determined but dot product is not defined in $L^1$.

Comment: That's probably why!

Comment: is that not defined?

Comment: You might be interested in the ["almost perpendicular lemma"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz's_lemma). (More formally called the Riesz lemma.) Even though there is no notion of orthogonality in $L^1$, one can find a vector $v$ that is "almost perpendicular" to a closed subspace which can sometimes suffice in arguments. (For instance, the non-compactness of the unit ball in an infinite dimensional space.)

Comment: This could be of interest:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood%E2%80%93Paley_theory

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: Instead of **orthogonality**, one can refer to **duality** ... with space $L^{\infty}$.

Comment: Perhaps, this reference might interest you as well (http://www.chioka.in/differences-between-the-l1-norm-and-the-l2-norm-least-absolute-deviations-and-least-squares/)

Comment: A very complete set of lecture notes on functional analysis (http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Functional%20Analysis2.pdf)